# The performance degradation when adding the delete_flag condition in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a billing table and a contract table.

```
create table billing (
   org_id character varying(5) not null
   , billing_id character varying(20) not null
   , contract_key character varying(30) not null
   , started_date character varying(8) not null
   , primary key (org_id, billing_id, contract_key, started_date)
);

create table contract (
   org_id character varying(5) not null
   , contract_key character varying(30) not null
   , apply_started_date character varying(8) not null
   , delete_flag character varying(1)
   , primary key (org_id, contract_key, apply_started_date)
);
```

There are 2 million records in the billing table and 3.5 million records in the contract table.

I need to join billing table and contract table. Also, the contract table must be joined with the record with the latest apply_started_date.

I created the query below.

```
select * from billing
left join contract
on billing.org_id = contract.org_id
and billing.contract_key = contract.contract_key
inner join (
   select org_id, contract_key, MAX(apply_started_date) as max_apply_started_date
   from contract
   where apply_started_date::integer < 20230829
   group by org_id, contract_key
) contract_aggregate
on contract.org_id = contract_aggregate.org_id
and contract.contract_key = contract_aggregate.contract_key
and contract.apply_started_date = contract_aggregate.max_apply_started_date
where billing.org_id = '001'
and billing.billing_id in ('B000000000000001','B000000000000002','B000000000000003','B000000000000004','B000000000000005')
and contract.apply_started_date::integer < 20230829
```

The performance of this query is fine. Results are obtained in 127msec.

However, if you add the condition contract.delete_flag=0 to the above query, the performance will immediately deteriorate! It takes 3586msec.

```
select * from billing
left join contract
on billing.org_id = contract.org_id
and billing.contract_key = contract.contract_key
inner join (
   select org_id, contract_key, MAX(apply_started_date) as max_apply_started_date
   from contract
   where apply_started_date::integer < 20230829
   and delete_flag = '0'
   group by org_id, contract_key
) contract_aggregate
on contract.org_id = contract_aggregate.org_id
and contract.contract_key = contract_aggregate.contract_key
and contract.apply_started_date = contract_aggregate.max_apply_started_date
where billing.org_id = '001'
and billing.billing_id in ('B000000000000001','B000000000000002','B000000000000003','B000000000000004','B000000000000005')
and contract.apply_started_date::integer < 20230829
and delete_flag = '0'
```

I don't understand why just referencing the delete flag causes such bad performance.
Even adding an index to the delete flag did not work. By the way, more than 95% of the actual data has delete_flag=0.
How can I do it faster?

I have attached both execution plans for your reference.

No condition for delete_flag:

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop (cost=23.41..239297.08 rows=1 width=174) (actual time=0.075..0.096 rows=5 loops=1)
   Join Filter: ((billing.contract_key)::text = (contract.contract_key)::text)
   -> Merge Join (cost=22.85..239294.65 rows=3 width=128) (actual time=0.066..0.073 rows=5 loops=1)
         Merge Cond: ((contract_1.contract_key)::text = (billing.contract_key)::text)
         -> GroupAggregate (cost=0.56..224689.00 rows=1166664 width=67) (actual time=0.030..0.035 rows=6 loops=1)
               Group Key: contract_1.org_id, contract_1.contract_key
               -> Index Only Scan using contract_pkey on contract contract_1 (cost=0.56..204272.38 rows=1166664 width=44) (actual time=0.025..0.028 rows=7 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: (org_id = '001'::text)
                     Filter: ((apply_started_date)::integer < 20230829)
                     Heap Fetches: 0
         -> Sort (cost=22.30..22.31 rows=5 width=61) (actual time=0.034..0.034 rows=5 loops=1)
               Sort Key: billing.contract_key
               Sort Method: quicksort Memory: 25kB
               -> Index Only Scan using billing_pkey on billing (cost=0.43..22.24 rows=5 width=61) (actual time=0.015..0.024 rows=5 loops=1)
                     Index Cond: ((org_id = '001'::text) AND (billing_id = ANY ('{B000000000000001,B000000000000002,B000000000000003,B000000000000004,B000000000000005}'::text[]) ))
                     Heap Fetches: 0
   -> Index Scan using contract_pkey on contract (cost=0.56..0.80 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=5)
         Index Cond: (((org_id)::text = '001'::text) AND ((contract_key)::text = (contract_1.contract_key)::text) AND ((apply_started_date)::text = (max(( contract_1.apply_started_date)::text))))
         Filter: ((apply_started_date)::integer < 20230829)
Planning Time: 0.610ms
Execution Time: 0.127ms
```

With delete_flag condition:

```
QUERY PLAN
Nested Loop  (cost=229048.18..266966.69 rows=1 width=174) (actual time=3228.310..3228.334 rows=5 loops=1)
  Join Filter: ((billing.contract_key)::text = (contract.contract_key)::text)
  ->  Merge Join  (cost=229047.62..266964.26 rows=3 width=128) (actual time=3228.285..3228.292 rows=5 loops=1)
        Merge Cond: ((contract_1.contract_key)::text = (billing.contract_key)::text)
        ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=229025.33..252358.61 rows=1166664 width=67) (actual time=3228.213..3228.218 rows=6 loops=1)
              Group Key: contract_1.org_id, contract_1.contract_key
              ->  Sort  (cost=229025.33..231941.99 rows=1166664 width=44) (actual time=3228.200..3228.201 rows=7 loops=1)
                    Sort Key: contract_1.contract_key
                    Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 184760kB
                    ->  Seq Scan on contract contract_1  (cost=0.00..111460.84 rows=1166664 width=44) (actual time=0.030..2114.875 rows=3500000 loops=1)
                          Filter: (((delete_flag)::text = '0'::text) AND ((org_id)::text = '001'::text) AND ((apply_started_date)::integer < 20230829))
        ->  Sort  (cost=22.30..22.31 rows=5 width=61) (actual time=0.066..0.067 rows=5 loops=1)
              Sort Key: billing.contract_key
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
              ->  Index Only Scan using billing_pkey on billing  (cost=0.43..22.24 rows=5 width=61) (actual time=0.039..0.050 rows=5 loops=1)
                    Index Cond: ((org_id = '001'::text) AND (billing_id = ANY ('{B000000000000001,B000000000000002,B000000000000003,B000000000000004,B000000000000005}'::text[])))
                    Heap Fetches: 0
  ->  Index Scan using contract_pkey on contract  (cost=0.56..0.80 rows=1 width=46) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=5)
        Index Cond: (((org_id)::text = '001'::text) AND ((contract_key)::text = (contract_1.contract_key)::text) AND ((apply_started_date)::text = (max((contract_1.apply_started_date)::text))))
        Filter: (((delete_flag)::text = '0'::text) AND ((apply_started_date)::integer < 20230829))
Planning Time: 0.653 ms
Execution Time: 3586.872 ms
```

Comment: I think it is likely due to the way the PostgreSQL query planner optimizes the query.

Comment: Run the ANALYZE command on your tables to update the statistics, which can help the query planner make better decisions. ANALYZE billing;
ANALYZE contract;

Comment: Are these plan presented verbatim?  The lack of Rows Removed by Filter lines seems rather suspicious.

Comment: You need to tell us the version of PostgreSQL.

Comment: I tried ANALYZE command but no improvement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues with the data model and query. The columns `billing.started_date` and `contract.apply_started_date` should be of type `date` instead of a character type. As a general principle, columns should be of a data type most closely related to their intended use. The query is overly complex, the following query should produce identical results (with the exception of redundant `org_id` and `contract_key` columns that were produced in the original query by the join to the `aggregate_contract` subquery:

```
SELECT *, MAX(contract.apply_started_date) OVER (PARTITION BY contract.org_id, contract.contract_key) AS max_apply_started_date
  FROM billing
  JOIN contract
    ON billing.org_id = contract.org_id
       AND billing.contract_key = contract.contract_key
  WHERE billing.org_id = '001'
    AND billing.billing_id IN ('B000000000000001', 'B000000000000002', 'B000000000000003', 'B000000000000004', 'B000000000000005')
    AND contract.apply_started_date < '20230829'
    AND contract.delete_flag = '0';
```

One of the problems in the original query is the non-sargable use of `contract.apply_started_date`. Because that column is being cast to `integer`,  it is being used as a filter on the index scans instead of part of the search criteria. The above query removes the cast, which should be safe given the structure of the text date representation (using a `date` type for the column, as previously mentioned, is a cleaner approach).

I suspect that the execution planner chose a sequential scan of `constract` for the original query with `delete_flag` criteria because it estimated that the combination of a non-sargable use of `apply_started_date` along with the addition of the `delete_flag` criteria would be more efficiently handled with a sequential scan. If 95% of the rows have `delete_flag = '0'`, an index on `delete_flag` is unlikely to be used because it is insufficiently selective.

There are likely additional performance improvement that can be made. I've not created synthetic data to test this query, so it's possible that I've made a mistake in simplifying the original.

Comment: The point that the data type is inappropriate is completely correct.
However, the data type cannot be changed because it affects other systems.
So, I created a materialized view that converted `apply_started_date` to date type and referenced this view, the performance improved dramatically! (3586msec -> 147msec)
I'm thinking of moving in this direction for now. Thank you for your advice.